# Getting XML back from a web service when it should be JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am a noob to ASP.NET/C#.  I am trying to use a web service to return a JSON object from the database.  I am getting an error in Firebug that I am creating a circular reference.  The stack trace is in JSON format.  When I view the web service directly in the browser, it is returning valid XML for some strange reason.  Here is my web service.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public DataSet Posts() {
    string connString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XXX"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Posts";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
}
```

I'm new to C# so I don't know if this is written correctly.  What I want is a DataSet in JSON format.  Am I doing this correctly?  Here is the jQuery that is calling the web service.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebServices/MessageBoard.asmx/Posts",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) { console.log(data) },
            failure: function (msg) {
                //alert(msg);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I wrote the web service, so yes I have access to it.

Comment: It is displayed above.  I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting XML is because the the `DataSet` serializes to XML. However, you can use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to turn the XML into JSON. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { dataTable.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column{0}", i), typeof(string)); }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            var vals = new List<object>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) { vals.Add(string.Format("Value {0}", j)); }
            dataTable.LoadDataRow(vals.ToArray(), true);
        }

        dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
        dataSet.AcceptChanges();

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks, Mike.  I didn't even know where to start.

Comment: Why do I have to write it to a file?  I can view the XML in my browser.

Comment: @shummel7845: there you go! I actually didn't need to serialize the `DataSet` first as I had rememberd, much easier!

Comment: Great.  Two questions.  One, why is the for loop running 5 times?  Why 5?  And two, can I use return instead of console.writeline for my web service?

Comment: Figured it out.  That was just an example table.  Duh.  And yes, you can use return.