# Conversion from DataSet to JSON ends up wrapping the JSON string with xml tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I did lots of research before I come here and none of the "solutions" gave me what I wanted so that's why I'm posting here.

I'm working with ASP.NET C#.

I have a web service which I'm currently trying to get to return JSON strings instead of xml.

Here's one method of the service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String SelectHrana(String ime)
    {
        //HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cnnstring);
        con.Open();
        String pom = "select * from Food where Name like ('%' + @Ime + '%')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pom, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ime", ime);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    }
```

This returns the following:

*`<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> { "Table": [ { "ID": 1, "Name": "boiled egg", "Calories": 155 }, { "ID": 2, "Name": "strawberry", "Calories": 33 } ] }
</string>`*

Could anyone tell me how to get rid of the `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">` at the beginning and the `</string>` at the end?

Thank you.

Comment: simple way - String.Replace("<string xmlns='http ://tempuri.org//'>","").Replace("</string>","");

Comment: Well I was trying to find a way to do that without touching the string at all and just making JSON.NET do the work. Thanks you for your answer.

Comment: this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644145/getting-xml-back-from-a-web-service-when-it-should-be-json

looks like your exact problem

Comment: Just tried Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds)); and it gave me a completely blank page :/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any good way to return pure JSON from WCF project nor ASMX despite all "Experts" saying "its easy"
Add web page to your project (ASPX) which can use your web service as data source and then to serialize the objects from the web service JSON.

By using:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
String myJSON= serializer.Serialize(<your object>);
```

And "myJSON" will hold the JSON.

The JavaScriptSerializer  can't handle DataTable\DataSet so what you can do is to insert DataSet into DataTable and use the following method to convert it to JSON (string)

```
 public static string GetDataTableToJSONString(DataTable table)
        {

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> list = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    dict[col.ColumnName] = row[col];
                }
                list.Add(dict);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(list);
        }
```

//To return JSONP
Also, sometime you need to return its in JSONP format so I used a Request parameter and if it exist I use it as the wrapper for my JSON in the end of the Page_Load method on the page I'm targeting from the client :

```
 String callBack = Request["callback"];
 if (callBack != null)
            {

                Response.Write(callBack + "(" + GetDataTableToJSONString(GetDiamonds(paramList)) + ")");
            }
            else
                Response.Write(GetDataTableToJSONString(GetDiamonds(paramList)));
```